# jQuery - click / animte

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate

https://jsfiddle.net/SUCHiJS/07jorqjg/1/

```
var showInfo = function () {
          $('.infoButton').click( function() {
              $('#info').animate( {
                  right: '0px'
              }, 600)
              $('body').animate( {
                  right: '60%'
              }, 600)
          } );

          $('.infoButton').click( function() {
              $('#info').animate( {
                  right: '-60%'
              }, 200)
              $('body').animate( {
                  right: '0px'
              }, 200)
          } );
      }
$(document).ready(showInfo);
```

I have problem with click function. When class of div was called "click" everything works and while I've changed to "infoButton". Div started to be unclickable.

Comment: You should be using [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: You have two click events, they do opposite things, they are BOTH BEING CALLED when you click on the button, every time.  If you want something to toggle, you need to use `.toggle()`.  Go look at the examples on the API page I linked.